# how to select a range of row in table in webdriver?

Tags: webdriver

I have the following html, there might be rows before the first row or rows after the last row I pasted, and I need to select ALL the rows follow the row containing "order number" cell, all the way up to the row contining "total", in the following case, I need to select 2 rows , one contain 123, and another one contains 456.

```
<tr>
   <td> order number </td>
   <td> order unit  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td> 123 </td>
   <td> 123  </td>
</tr>


<tr>
   <td> 456 </td>
   <td> 456 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td> total </td>
   <td> 579  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements I think the easiest thing for you to do would be to select `IWebElements` that are found at your table row level.  Then you can loop through the elements and compare child elements text to the numbers that you want.  If the number doesn't match your first number then delete the element from the list.

After you find the first number set a flag that tells you not to delete and then check for the second number.  It will skip the deletion, until you find the second number and then that would toggle the flag to delete again.  At this point you could just have a delete for each one without the check or you can use the flag delete again.

Then you should have an implementation of `IWebElements` where you only have rows that match your requirements.

The only catch would be if you had repeated numbers that were part of your criteria...which would have to be a one off of this.